# How to print json data with ajax in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

How to print this JSON data with ajax in Laravel? this is a laravel and ajax app. I don't want to show json data to the public but in a nice way. try [there](http://ajaxcrud.habiburrahman.live/client)

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.",
"errors":{"image":["The image field is required."]}}
```

Comment: use `{!! $your_variable !!}` on view

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: need to print this validation error report in a nice way

Answer (score 0):

If any validation error occurs, Laravel redirects back with a variable [`$errors`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) accessible in blade.

In your view (blade) file, you can do :

```
@if ($errors->any())
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <div>{{$error}}</div>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

Then if there is any validation error, it will show one below another.